# Drupal menu block not showing up on certain pages

Tags: drupal, multilingual, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-blocks

I'm working on a e commerce Drupal website which was originally in one language, but needs to have an additional language added.
All the menu items are combined in one large 'Main Menu'. 
For the top level navigation of the site, they are using a menu block showing the 1st level of items. Then when navigating to the 'Products' section, they have a 2nd level of menu items, automatically generated with the Taxonomy Menu module, which are being showed in an other 'category' menu block, where you can browse trough the different product categories, linked as term reference to the taxonomy.

For translating, I decided to make new menus for the second language.
So basically there's:

Main menu lvl 1 - NL (menu block)
Main menu lvl 1 - FR (menu block)

Navigation menu lvl 2 - NL (menu block)
Navigation menu lvl 2 - FR (menu block)

The generated taxonomy menu's also come from 2 diffrent language vocabularies.

The taxonomy menu blocks are configured to only show in their matching languages (only restriction is not to be shown on the front page).

**Issue I'm having:**

On most pages, my translation lvl 2 navigation menu is showing fine, but after hours of trying different configurations, i can't seem to have it work on for instance:

www.site.be/fr/cart

My language detection is configured to look at the URL prefix (/fr/), so it should detect as being a french page, where my lvl 2 navigation menu should be shown.

The "sidebar_left" theme HTML code isn't even there, where he should put his menu block in.

Comment: maybe just add /fr/* and /fr

Comment: I've tried this, didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_block to display the menu on pages it wouldn't show up, cause there wasn't enough time to find the root of the problem.